# Calculate Pi using Monte Carlo

Tags: c++, numerical-methods

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>


#ifdef USE_OLD_RAND

#include <stdlib.h>
inline double getRandDart() {return rand() * 1.0 / RAND_MAX;}

#else

#include <random>
std::default_random_engine              generator;
std::uniform_real_distribution<double>  distribution(0,1);
inline double getRandDart() {return distribution(generator);}

#endif


// Monte Carlo Simulator to estimate the value of PI.
//
// If we have a circle with a radius of 1.
// Then the smallest square that encloses the circle as sides of length 2.
//
//      Area of circle pi r^2   = pi
//      Area of square 2.r.2.r  = 4
//
//          Ratio of overlapping area:      pi/4
//
// If we throw darts randomly at a dart board (with an even distribution) and always hit the square.
// Then the ratio of darts falling into the circle should be pi/4 of the total number of darts thrown.
//
//      pi/4 * countInSquare  = countInCircle
//
//      pi = 4 . countInCircle / countInSquare
//
// To simplify the maths.
// We will set the center point as 0,0 and only use the top right quadrant of the circle.
// We have 1/4 the size of the square and circle but the same maths still apply.
//
// A dart thrown has a random x/y value in the range 0->1 (top right quadrant).
// A dart is outside the circle if x^2 + y^2 > 1  (note 1^2 is 1)
//

int main()
{

    long     countInSquare   = 0;
    long     countInCircle   = 0;

    for(long iteration = 0; iteration <= 10'000'000'000; ++iteration) {
        double x = getRandDart();
        double y = getRandDart();

        double d = (x * x) + (y * y);

        countInSquare   += 1;
        countInCircle   += (d >= 1.0) ? 0 : 1;

        if (iteration % 10'000'000 == 0) {
            std::cout << iteration << " " << (4.0 * countInCircle / countInSquare) << "\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n" << std::setprecision(9) << (4.0 * countInCircle / countInSquare) << "\n";

}
```

Output:

```
> ./a.out
9990000000 3.14158
10000000000 3.14158


3.14158355
```

Comment: Your comment says that x*x+y*y==1 is not outside the circle (hence it is inside), but your code considers it outside.  Which way is the correct interpretation?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: Good catch. Stupid comments; why don't they compile so we can check the code matches the comments.

Comment: There are languages where that's kind of true (but also means that you can get syntax errors with your comments)

Comment: @Foon Interesting! Do you have any examples?

Comment: Spark is the first one that comes to mind (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPARK_(programming_language)) ... I was thinking Eiffel also did it, but actually, Eiffel's contracts are probably natively supported (Spark is basically a subset of Ada with additional things embedded in Ada compilers for the Spark checker to work with)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One could consider at least the following points:

- Instead of including `<stdlib.h>`, I'd include `<cstdlib>`.
- In `getRandDart()`, it *might* in this case be more readable to do `static_cast<double>(rand()) / RAND_MAX;` instead of multiplying by `1.0`.
- In the for loop, all of `x`, `y` and `d` can be const, so I'd make them const. This has the potential to protect the programmer from unintended mistakes, and can sometimes allow the compiler to optimize better.
- When you increment by one (in `countInSquare += 1;`), it makes more sense to use the `++` operator, i.e., to just write `++countInSquare`. This is more idiomatic and protects us from unintended mistakes: ++ conveys the meaning of increment (by one), whereas with `+=` we might accidentally write `+= 2;` and that would be perfectly valid (but not what we wanted).
- Regardless of the above point, notice that during the for-loop, it holds that `iteration == countInSquare`. So strictly speaking, the variable `countInSquare` is unnecessary and could be replaced by just `iteration` when needed.
- You could consider making the number of iterations and the second operand of the `%` operand constants to allow for easier modification and perhaps to slightly improve readability.
- Instead of typing `(4.0 * countInCircle / countInSquare)` twice, we could make a function that takes the two variables as parameters. This would allow us to save some typing, and again to protect us from unintended mistakes.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <random>
std::default_random_engine              generator;
```

If you require portable and reproducible results from  your random engine, consider specifying the exact random engine you want instead of relying on an implementation-defined alias.

```
// GCC & Clang
using minstd_rand0 = linear_congruential_engine<uint_fast32_t, 16807, 0, 2147483647>;
using default_random_engine = minstd_rand0;

// MSVC
using default_random_engine = mt19937;
```

---

```
std::uniform_real_distribution<double>  distribution(0,1);
```

For distributions, the standard doesn't require the result to be reproducible and identical across all implementations.  If you care for portability, you'll need to write/copy the specific distribution behavior you want.

---

```
inline double getRandDart() {return distribution(generator);}

// A dart thrown has a random x/y value in the range 0->1 (top right quadrant).
// A dart is outside the circle if x^2 + y^2 > 1  (note 1^2 is 1)
```

This is an example of where the comment doesn't match the function. The function `getRandDart()` doesn't return a dart. It returns a single magnitude instead of a Dart/Vec2d.

---

```
    for(long iteration = 0; iteration <= 10'000'000'000; ++iteration) {
```

Did you intend for ten billion and one iterations (`<=`)?

---

```
    long     countInSquare   = 0;
    for(long iteration = 0; iteration <= 10'000'000'000; ++iteration) {
        countInSquare   += 1;
        if (iteration % 10'000'000 == 0) {
             std::cout << iteration << " " << (4.0 * countInCircle / countInSquare) << "\n";
```

Do you need `countInSquare`? Both `iteration` and `countInSquare` are maintaining the same count.

When you don't care for the size in which an integer can represent because the value is countable, simply use `int`. In this case, you went with `long` as you needed a larger integral type to hold a value that couldn't be represented by an `int`. Compiling in an environment where `long` is 32-bit (windows) would obviously be bad. In these cases, use a specific fixed width integer type from `<cstdint>`. `auto` also works in determining the correct type (64-bit `long` on gcc/clang, 64-bit `long long` on msvc).

---

```
        countInCircle   += (d >= 1.0) ? 0 : 1;
```

Compilers are nice nowadays and optimized your ternary add.

```
        countInCircle   += (d < 1.0);
```

---

You can tighten the inner loop by reorganizing the operations. Rather than checking every iteration to report, tile the iterations into groups that calculate between reports.

```
    constexpr auto totalIterations = 10'000'000'001;
    constexpr auto reportInterval = 10'000'000;
    constexpr auto reports = std::div(totalIterations, reportInterval);

    while (reports.quot--) {
        for (auto iteration = 0; iteration < reportInterval; ++iteration) {
            const auto x = getRandDart();
            const auto y = getRandDart();
            const auto d = x * x + y * y;
            countInCircle += (d < 1.0);
        }
        countInSquare += reportInterval;
        std::cout << countInSquare << " " << (4.0 * countInCircle / countInSquare) << "\n";
    }

    while (reports.rem--) {
        const auto x = getRandDart();
        const auto y = getRandDart();
        const auto d = x * x + y * y;
        countInCircle += (d < 1.0);
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n" << std::setprecision(9) << (4.0 * countInCircle / totalIterations) << "\n";
```